# BERT sentence embeddings using pretrained models for Non-English text

Tags: python, nlp, cosine-similarity, bert-language-model, sentence-similarity

I am trying to apply `BERT` sentence embeddings to find similar sentences given a text piece in Swedish from a corpus of text strings in Swedish.
Sentence `BERT` from sentence_transformers (`SBERT`) seems to be the ideal choice. They have various pretrained models and give excellent examples:
(https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers)

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import torch

embedder = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')

sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.', 
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

Their choice for non-English Sentence Transformers, however, seems to be limited. I was wondering whether it's possible and perhaps more accurate to apply a BERT model from the Hugging Face library specifically trained on Swedish text or any other Non-English language for that matter on extracting sentence embeddings? Wouldn't a BERT model specifically trained on a language yield more accurate sentence embeddings for that language? In the end all models are pretrained on the same tasks MLM and NSP in their respective language to understand that language, right?

Any thoughts or experiences?

The ultimate goal is to use cosine similarity on the sentence embeddings to rank similar sentences/paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

Using a pretrained BERT for Swedish is much better indeed. The reason is that Swedish words are all outliers for BERT trained on an English corpus. So even if an English BERT might do some job on a Swedish corpus, a Swedish BERT is an obvious choice if available.

However if you face a possibility of mixed language corpus, then you cannot apply this approach, because not only will you need a separate BERT for every language involved, you also will need to detect languages used, including intra-sentence level. In this case, a possible solution would be to translate all the texts from "Autodetect language" to English, using Hugging Face networks or any public translation API. E.g. Google, Deepl, Yandex or Baidu.

P.S. if you happen to try both BERT's, could you pls share the quality difference in a comment here

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your swift reaction!

Do you happen to know if it's possible to just change the pretrained BERT model in 
embedder = SentenceTransformer('....') with another pretrained BERT from the huggingface library that's not originally from the Sentence BERT creators?
Or should I just get a pretrained Swedish model from the Huggingface library and extract the embeddings myself in some way?
Does it require a fine-tuned BERT? I just want to have contextualized embeddings of my Swedish sentences and compare them with cosine similarity (unsupervised).
Thanks again :)

Comment: That's definitely something determined by experimenting. Do you have them both at hand? Try both and report the quality pls